# Having trouble texturing this box

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to texture a box I'm making to put in a game and I've tried a bunch of different ways.[image]
i added the texture to the node but when i try to unwrap it does nothing. any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: You are in solid shading mode. Change to rendered view. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL3eL.png

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html

Comment: still had no luck any ideas?

Comment: @cegaton i changed it and its still not unwrapping idk what to do lol im very new at this so sorry if im annoying

Comment: have you unwrapped your whole object? It's not clear... You need to unwrap the whole object if you want the image texture to be displayed on all its faces